# Is Standard SQL better than Legacy SQL in terms of query optimization?

Tags: google-bigquery

On this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) page by Google, it goes through some advantages of Standard SQL, but I don't see anything in particular about efficiency.

I am creating some views in Google BigQuery, and the query is possible in both Legacy and Standard. I wanted to know if running query in standard SQL is more efficient than running in Legacy SQL. Is one type of SQL statement more optimized/efficient than the other?

All the views follow the below format (Inner join between two tables):

```
SELECT c.value, d.value2 
FROM TableA c
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id, value2
   FROM TableB 
) d
ON d.id = c.id
```

EDIT:

I ran two identical query on the same dataset and the following are the resulting plans

Legacy SQL[image]

Standard SQL [image]

I am having a hard time interpreting this, which one had the better result?

Comment: Write it both ways yourself, run them against the same data, and see which performs best in your particular circumstance against your particular data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to #standardSQL when possible: Even if there are any performance advantages today in legacy, all future performance improvements will happen in the standard SQL side.

Comment: if the execution difference is an more than hour would you still recommending switching to standard ?

Comment: I'd recommend filing a bug report and the team would jump to fix that. They are pretty serious about improving #standardSQL. In the meantime, use the faster one.

Comment: I love your optimism about the time of fixing bugs.